# Overloaded method value withBody with alternatives error mockserver in scala

Tags: scala, mockserver

I am trying to use mockserver to mock an API for testing. I am creating expectations using this:

```scala
    import org.mockserver.model.ParameterBody._
    import org.mockserver.model.Parameter._
    ...

    mockServer
      .when(
        request()
          .withPath(callEndpoint)
          .withMethod("POST")
          .withBody(params(
            param("email", "joe.blogs@gmail.com"),
            param("password", "secure_Password123")
          ))
      ).respond(response().withBody(responseBody))
```

Which to me seems very similar to what you can find in the MockServer documentation [here](http://www.mock-server.com/mock_server/creating_expectations.html#button_match_request_by_form_submission_body).

But I am getting the error:

```
Error:(115, 12) overloaded method value withBody with alternatives:
  (x$1: org.mockserver.model.Body[_])org.mockserver.model.HttpRequest <and>
  (x$1: Array[Byte])org.mockserver.model.HttpRequest <and>
  (x$1: String)org.mockserver.model.HttpRequest
 cannot be applied to (org.mockserver.model.ParameterBody)
          .withBody(params(
```

Does anybody has an idea what may I be doing wrong?

I am using Scala 2.11.8 and MockServer 5.6.0

Comment: Any updates on this? I am facing the same problem with MockServer 5.6.1 and Scala 2.11.8, in my case when passing a new `JsonBody` object to the `withBody` method.

Comment: Just found a workaround, just append `.asInstanceOf[Body[_]]`